# Ping hosts based on filter and return dead or alive

Tags: bash, rhel, ping

I am trying to create a script that is capable of pinging multiple hosts from a text file in my directory. The hosts are with specific naming conventions and are grouped. E.g in the text fie

```
10.10.10.10 XX-YY_ZZ name of the host in form of URL
```

The file is not CSV but txt.

What I am hoping to make is something simple which when you run say `pingme YY` (where `YY` is the in common element of the devices belonging to a certain location) it would return me a result of e.g:

```
XX-YY_ZZ = ALIVE
```

Probably is very simple but I have no idea how to even start as this is Linux REDHAT we are running.

Any pointers and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: So you will have multiple hosts with `YY` in the name and you want the script to ping all of them and return a single status or a status for each one?  Also can you post a redacted sample line from your input file in your question so I can see how many columns/separators are in it exactly?

Comment: a simple tool for this is Ansible. Use it and get your stuff done very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exit code from `ping` to determine if ping succeeded or failed.

```
ping HOST -c1 > /dev/null && echo "ALIVE" || echo "DEAD"
```

When host is alive exit code is 0, and for dead 1. To ping every host you can loop each line and use `awk` to get the first column which contains address/hostname.

```
exec 3<input.txt

while read -u3 line
do
    if [ "$line" == "" ]; then
        # skip empty lines
        continue
    fi

    ping -c1 $(echo "$line"| awk '{print $1}') > /dev/null

    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo "$line=ALIVE"
    else
        echo "$line=DEAD"
    fi
done
```

**EDIT:**

If you want only to ping host by matching a single line in the file, you can grep it:

```
# find line for $host, only 1 line
line = grep "$HOST" input.txt |tail -n 1

# $($line |awk '{print $1}') outputs the first column of line (address)
ping -c1 $($line |awk '{print $1}') >/dev/null && echo "$line=ALIVE" || echo "$line=DEAD"
```

Comment: Yes but I have multiple hosts per location. So HOST = what is in common in the name of the hosts, correct ? Where exactly in script is the host referance though....I mean if I specify it in the command under HOST ?

Comment: So you have more than one host per line? `$(echo "$line"| awk '{print $1}')` outputs the first column in the row (assumed hostname/ip address).

Comment: I don't think the `-q` switch is available in redhat `ping`.  It's not on centos 7 anyway.  Also the `-W1` switch helped a lot in my answer.  By default it waits 20 seconds for a timeout which could make this task take a really long time if a lot of nodes are down.

Comment: I'll remove it since should work without `-q` just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
pingme () {
hostfile="/home/jbutryn/test/hostfile.txt"
IFS= mapfile -t  hosts < <(cat $hostfile)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    match=$(echo "$host" | grep -o "\-$1_" | sed 's/-//' | sed 's/_//')
    if [[ "$match" = "$1" ]]; then
        hostname=$(echo "$host" | awk '{print $2}')
        ping -c1 -W1 $(echo "$host" | awk '{print $1}') > /dev/null
        if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
            echo "$hostname is alive"
        elif [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
            echo "$hostname is dead"
        fi
    fi
done
}
```

You can run this function like:  `pingme UR01` and it should return something like:

```
[root@JBCLAMP001 test]# pingme CC
BB-CC_DD is dead
AA-CC_EE is alive
[root@JBCLAMP001 test]# pingme DD
CC-DD_EE is dead
CC-DD_JJ is alive
```

Comment: I suspect this is exactly what is needed. Is that shell though ....cause I got it on shell and produced me an error ( line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{  )

Comment: Uhm. Much of it is in bash syntax.  In order to use it you can add it to a file and `source file` or `. file`.  Or if you want it to be a more permanent solution  you can source that file from your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Additionally ensure the file doesn't have any windows special characters in it.  I wrote that with `LF` line breaks but it was pasted to the site on a windows machine so it may have added some `CR` characters too.  You can check this with a text editor like notepadd++ or similar.

Comment: I have tried and tried and it`s not working . Tried modifying it  - noting . i have 2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64 Linux , I have the file in .sh , run it via ./ , the txt file I tried to change the order , small letters , big letters- nothing, no errors no nothing as it isn`t reading the file.

Comment: Still no luck after a year